# use $lookup on sub array by foreign key

Tags: mongodb

What I'm searching for seems pretty straightforward but everything I find is for a slightly different configuration and I'm having a hard time understanding how they work.

simplified parent document model

```
{
  parentId: string,
  votes: [
    { voteId: string, something: number }
  ]
}
```

simplified vote document model

```
{
  voteId: string,
  name: string
}
```

desired outcome

```
{
  parentId: string,
  votes: [
    { voteId: string, something: number, name: string }
  ]
}
```

So basically the outcome is that everything is left in tact on the parent.votes document (`voteId`, `something`), but for each vote document, I merge the document from the votes collection. (`voteId`, `name`, ...rest)

I noticed that an empty pipeline gets me 80% of the way there, but I lose the values previously stored on parent.votes document

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'registration',
    let: {
      votes: '$votes',
    },
    pipeline: [],
    as: 'votes',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.  To *"merge"* all fields from the `registration` collection, see below.

```js
db.candidates.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "registration",
      "localField": "votes.voteId",
      "foreignField": "voteId",
      "as": "voters"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "votes": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$votes",
          "as": "vote",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$vote",
              {
                "name": {
                  "$getField": {
                    "field": "name",
                    "input": {
                      "$first": {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": "$voters",
                          "as": "voter",
                          "cond": {"$eq": ["$$vote.voteId", "$$voter.voteId"]}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unset": "voters"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qm7JrrBubdT).

##### Merging all fields from the `registration` collection

If you want to merge all fields from the `registration` collection into the `votes` object, you could simplify the above pipeline and do this.

```js
db.candidates.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "registration",
      "localField": "votes.voteId",
      "foreignField": "voteId",
      "as": "voters"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "votes": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$votes",
          "as": "vote",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$vote",
              {
                "$first": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$voters",
                    "as": "voter",
                    "cond": {"$eq": ["$$vote.voteId", "$$voter.voteId"]}
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unset": "voters"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ossfaIEtn6c).

Comment: this is definitely helpful, there is clearly a lot to the mongodb api that I have yet to learn. Is it possible to modify this to work for all fields on the `vote` document, where this currently appears to just grab `name`?

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Do you really want all fields, including, for example, `"_id"`?

Comment: yes, if that's possible

Comment: actually I was able to figure it out with your answer, thanks!

Comment: @stackoverfloweth I updated the answer to merge all `registration` fields.